# How to ensure all nested attributes show during 'edit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I currently have a nested model **User** has_many **Sales_Orders** has_many **Items**.

I can create the **Sales_Order** with nested **Items** properly but when I try to 'edit' the **Sales_Order**, the Sales_Order information is visible but the **Items** are not shown. Any idea why these wouldn't show?

```
[sales_orders_controller.rb]
...

def edit
  @sales_order = SalesOrder.find(params[:id])
end


[edit.html.erb]
<% provide(:title, "Edit SO") %>
<h1>Edit Sales Order</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@sales_order) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <div class="span3">
            <%= f.label :so, "SO#:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :so %>

            <%= f.label :customer, "Customer:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :customer %>

            <%= f.label :enter_date, "Date Entered:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :enter_date, value: date_formatter(@sales_order.enter_date) %>

            <%= f.label :request_date, "Request Date:"%>
            <%= f.text_field :request_date, value: date_formatter(@sales_order.request_date) %>

            <%= f.label :comments, "CS Comments:" %>
            <%= f.text_area :comments %>
        </div>

        <div class="span3">
            <% f.fields_for @sales_order.items do |builder| %>  
                <%= render 'item_fields', f: builder %>
            <% end %>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>

[_item_fields.erb]
<fieldset>
<%= f.label :item_code, "Item Code:" %>
<%= f.text_field :item_code %>

<%= f.label :qty_in_kg, "Qty (kg):" %>
<%= f.text_field :qty_in_kg %>

<%= f.label :qc_comments, "Comments:" %>
<%= f.text_field :qc_comments %>

<%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Do you have `Sales_Orders` or `Sales_Order` or `SalesOrder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% f.fields_for @sales_order.items do |builder| %>
```

should be

```
<%= f.fields_for @sales_order.items do |builder| %>
```

Without the `=` you're building the output in the loop but never rendering/printing the return value (the generated HTML output).

Comment: Thank you SO much. I have literally spent HOURS on this thinking it was something complicated I didn't understand about build. You indirectly solved another issue for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

Use `<%= f.fields_for @sales_order.items do |builder| %>`

Notice the **=** sign. This implies, **"evaluate and embed"**